# Postman response : Could not get any response from server

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, underscore.js, postman

I'm trying to create a todo-list app and checking it with POSTMAN on every type of request. GET and POST requests are working fine. But PUT and DELETE are not working as expected.

As expected means : It is not showing 404 neither showing results instead it's showing an error, i.e., Could not get any response.

Here's my code of put and delete :

```
var todos = [];

// DELETE /todos/:id

app.delete('/todos/:id', function(req,res){
    var todoId = parseInt(req.params.id, 10);
    var matchedTodo = _.findWhere(todos, {id: todoId});

    if(!matchedTodo){
        res.status(404).send();
    }else{
        todos = _.without(todos, matchedTodo);
        res.json(matchedTodo);
        //console.log(todos);
    }

});

// PUT /todos/:id

app.put('/todos/:id', function(req,res){

    var todoId = parseInt(req.params.id, 10);
    var matchedTodo = _.findWhere(todos, {id: todoId});
    var body = _.pick(req.body, 'description', 'completed');
    var validAttributes = {};

    if(!matchedTodo){
        return res.status(404).send();
    }

    if(body.hasOwnProperty('completed') && _.isBoolean(body.completed)){
        validAttributes.completed = body.completed;
    }else if(body.hasOwnProperty('completed')){
        return res.status(400).send();
    }

    if(body.hasOwnProperty('description') && _.isString(body.description) && body.description.trim().length > 0){
        body.description = body.description.trim();
        validAttributes.description = body.description;
    }else if(body.hasOwnProperty('description')){
        return res.status(400).send()
    }

    _.extend(matchedTodo, validAttributes);
    res.json(matchedTodo);



});
```

Now, I don't know if it's a bug or something.

Comment: what does your front end API call look like? [edit] nevermind that won't matter if you're testing in postman

Comment: are you making sure to pass in an ID into your URL for example `localhost:3000/todos/938502`

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Could not get any response" response when using postman with subdomain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47806876/could-not-get-any-response-response-when-using-postman-with-subdomain)

Answer (score 2):

First, you should try the official tips:

- The server couldn't send a response: *Ensure that the backend is working properly*
- Self-signed SSL certificates are being blocked: *Fix this by turning off '`SSL certificate verification`' in `Settings > General`*
- Proxy configured incorrectly: *Ensure that proxy is configured correctly in `Settings > Proxy`*
- Request timeout: *Change request timeout in `Settings > General`*

Second, normally **official tip 2** will solve this problem. If not, you may use environment variables. You should confirm the link (shown in the [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JzmJ9.png), the protocol) can be accessed.

If not, you should check your environment variable's current value. If the **current** value is `blank`, you should **fill in** and **set** the options you've changed in official tips to **default**. And the problem should be solved now.