# The server couldn't send a response

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, postman

Good day.
I know that this question is already ask before. But i can't really make this thing work.

I am using Visual Studio 2017

I am following a tutorial on how to Build an app with Asp.net core and angular

My problem is i can't send request to the site using postman.

I have read the answers from the link below but all of them is not working

["Could not get any response" response when using postman with subdomain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47806876/could-not-get-any-response-response-when-using-postman-with-subdomain)

This is my launchSettings.json

```
"DatingApp.API": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": false,
      "launchUrl": "api/values",
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5000",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
```

When i run the API

[image]

(https://localhost:5000/api/values) and send request using Postman.

It give's me error

[image]

And i'm also receiving error in the Visual Studio Output window

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel:Information: Connection id "0HLHTBLQGR6JP" bad request data: "Invalid request line: '\x16\x03\x01\x01\x01\x01\x00\x00\xFD\x03\x03e*\xD2K\x9C\xA5\x99\xAA\xB4.\x0C+\x8F\xE2\xFF\xB6$\x05\xDA\xA4\xD5a\xBD\x1Fx\xBB\x18\xF6\xE5\xD5fO\x00\x00n\xC0/\xC0+\xC00\xC0,\x00\x9E\xC0'\x00g\xC0(\x00k\xC0$\xC0\x14\xC0\x0A'"

Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.BadHttpRequestException: Invalid request line: '\x16\x03\x01\x01\x01\x01\x00\x00\xFD\x03\x03e*\xD2K\x9C\xA5\x99\xAA\xB4.\x0C+\x8F\xE2\xFF\xB6$\x05\xDA\xA4\xD5a\xBD\x1Fx\xBB\x18\xF6\xE5\xD5fO\x00\x00n\xC0/\xC0+\xC00\xC0,\x00\x9E\xC0'\x00g\xC0(\x00k\xC0$\xC0\x14\xC0\x0A'
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpParser`1.RejectRequestLine(Byte* requestLine, Int32 length)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpParser`1.GetUnknownMethod(Byte* data, Int32 length, Int32& methodLength)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpParser`1.ParseRequestLine(TRequestHandler handler, Byte* data, Int32 length)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpParser`1.ParseRequestLine(TRequestHandler handler, ReadOnlySequence`1& buffer, SequencePosition& consumed, SequencePosition& examined)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpParser`1.Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.IHttpParser<TRequestHandler>.ParseRequestLine(TRequestHandler handler, ReadOnlySequence`1& buffer, SequencePosition& consumed, SequencePosition& examined)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.Http1Connection.TakeStartLine(ReadOnlySequence`1 buffer, SequencePosition& consumed, SequencePosition& examined)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.Http1Connection.ParseRequest(ReadOnlySequence`1 buffer, SequencePosition& consumed, SequencePosition& examined)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.Http1Connection.TryParseRequest(ReadResult result, Boolean& endConnection)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol.ProcessRequests[TContext](IHttpApplication`1 application)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol.ProcessRequestsAsync[TContext](IHttpApplication`1 application)
```

But when i run the program using IIS Express. it works and i can send request using the Postman.

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: If your `launchSettings` specify port 5000, what is `http://localhost:39318` in your screenshot of Visual Studio?

Comment: Your `launchSettings` say `http` but you are using `https` in Postman

Comment: I can't believe it. my error is http and im using https in Postman. Thank you @SimplyGed for pointing it out