# Postman "Self-signed SSL certificates are being blocked"

Tags: rest, api, ssl-certificate, postman

I'm trying to send a POST request via postman and got below error:

[image: Self-signed SSL certificates are being blocked]

I believed I had some error with HTTPS link. Then I tried to **turned of** *"

> SSL certificated verification

"* in `Settings > General` as the guide already.
But it didn't help!!!

Answer (score 12):

I fixed this by following:
Postman -> File (1st menu item) -> Settings -> SSL certificate verification OFF

Comment: But what is the root cause of this error

Answer (score 4):

For Postman on a Mac, turn it off here:

File menu > Preferences > General > SSL Certificate Verification

Answer (score 2):

File >> Settings >> General

**Turn Off the SSL Certificate Verification**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I see the same issue and answers at: [this question 47806876](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47806876/could-not-get-any-response-response-when-using-postman-with-subdomain)

However, as my question it I couldn't find the right solution to me directly. After 1 hour of checking I found that *the error doesn't regard anything to SSL certificates and HTTPS*!!!

The error due to an ugly mistake with:

- **Some spaces in parameter "mykey  "**, see picture:

[image: SPACES in myKey parameter]

I fixed it by removing the "SPACES" then it work normally.
The point here I think it is a BUG in Postman, that need to be fix.
Means Postman should rise the correct error here, to save us hours of testing.

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed the issue ,  just open the postman then  setting (one which have the spanner like image) ==> General ==> SSL Certificate verification **Turn off**