# How to fix "Could not get any response" in Postman?

Tags: postman

Postman for Linux
Version 6.7.1
Deepin x64

I'm trying to test a get method on postman to test my code, but I always get this error message.

> Could not get any response.
>
> There was an error connecting to localhost:3001/blocks.
>
> Why this might have happened:
>
> The server couldn't send a response:
>
> Ensure that the backend is working properly
>
> Self-signed SSL certificates are being blocked:
>
> Fix this by turning off 'SSL certificate verification' in Settings > General
>
> Proxy configured incorrectly
>
> Ensure that proxy is configured correctly in Settings > Proxy
>
> Request timeout:
>
> Change request timeout in Settings > General

I've tried to do almost everything from this topic (["Could not get any response" response when using postman with subdomain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47806876/could-not-get-any-response-response-when-using-postman-with-subdomain)) but nothing seems to work.

This is the on the message console.

[Postman Console Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5qsZ6.png)

Someone can help me to fix this?

Comment: Your application code is probably not responding. I don't think this is something which postman can provide useful error messages for. Are you able to access your application using the browser/curl/wget/httpie?

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Could not get any response" response when using postman with subdomain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47806876/could-not-get-any-response-response-when-using-postman-with-subdomain)

Answer (score 6):

In Postman go to Postman-> Preferences and in the settings tab turn off SSL certificate Verification

Answer (score 0):

my project work try this:

1. Restart your web server local ex: wamp, postgree, oracle
2. in postman setting :

- Trim keys and values in request body OFF
- Use next generation URL processing ON
- SSL certificate verification OFF
- Always open request in web tab OFF
- Send no cache header ON
- Send postman token header ON
- Retain headers when clicking on links OFF
- Automatically follow redirects ON
- Send anonymous usage data to postman OFF

Answer (score 0):

It works for me:
Restart your web server like: PostgreSQL, Oracle
it will work

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

check what port your app is listening on if it's the same with the database port change it. would work. let me know if it was helpful

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).