# Postman "could not get any response, there was an error connecting to ."

Tags: postman

I am on Postman 7.5.0. 
I am calling one api from the postman, and get an error as "There was an error connecting to ." 
But when I executed the curl code generated from the postman, it worked just fine(they were also calling the app running on my pc).
I also tried to copy the link and sent to my coworker and they were getting correct responses too.

I referred to other questions related to this topic and turn off all proxy stuff, they didn't help.

My app has lots of apis and this is the only one that I could not get any response via postman call.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Could you include links to at least a couple questions you've looked through. ie. [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47806876/could-not-get-any-response-response-when-using-postman-with-subdomain) provides a litany of possible solutions, and seeing documentation that you've tried all of them could help to figure out what the root problem is here.

Comment: "I also tried to copy the link and sent to my coworker and they were getting correct responses too." Does that mean it worked in postman for a coworker?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you used chrome extension Postman Interceptor?

I think Postman is not able to intercept https or http request.

Follow the steps:

To use Interceptor with Postman Chrome, you can take the following steps:

1. Install Postman from the Chrome Web Store.
2. Install Interceptor from the Chrome Web Store.
3. Open Postman, click on the Interceptor icon(near the sync icon) in the toolbar, and toggle to On.

The Postman Chrome app's Interceptor functions as a proxy to capture HTTP and HTTPS requests.

More Information is available at https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/capturing-request-data/interceptor/#using-the-interceptor-with-postmans-chrome-app

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had to go to Settings -> "SSL Certificate Verification" and turn this off, and everything worked great.

Comment: Yes, this is the first thing I tried but still got the same error.

Comment: I had the same issue, I tried switching off and still same issue, ahs it been fixed?

Answer (score 0):

For my case, it was me mistakenly unchecked one of the postman default headers.